# Refer to PivotTable name in cell in GetPivotData

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, vba

I've to a formula like the one below.

```
=GetPivotData("number";'Sheet2'!$A$3)
```

Now, I want to make the second value, the 'PivotTable' value, variable. I have the variable value in a cell, so I tried something like the following

```
=GetPivotData("number";A1)
```

Cell A1 contains the following:

```
'Sheet2'!$A$3
```

For some reason, this doesn't work. I have no clue how to solve this and I can't seem to find it anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=GetPivotData("number";INDIRECT(A1))
```